# AWS EC2 - How to upgrade instance without changing existing public IP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

Is it possible to upgrade EC2 instance without changing existing public IP address? My mobile application is live and unfortunately we didn't use elastic IP in web services. So if I upgrade current instance, it will generate new public IP and the old application users won't be able to use mobile application. 
Is there any way to keep current IP as it is? Or any other way to upgrade it without loosing existing users? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what sort of software you are running exactly

If you have an application that is sessionless then it would be simple to bring up another server on a different IP and then use route53 to switch over the traffic, with both servers running at the same time

If the application is stateful though and if it stores the sessions locally on the host then that's more of a problem

One possible approach is to bind an elastic ip to the running host, reconfigure your software to listen on all addresses ( a lot of configuration controls allow this with an address of 0.0.0.0 ) then change DNS and gradually see the traffic migrate to the elastic IP, while both addresses work

Once the new address is fully in use (depends on your TTL) it becomes much easier to switch to a new host by reassigning the EIP

Comment: My application stores session locally, but I can control application users from server token, If I expire their token, then they will have to login again. Your idea about introducing new server is great, we are also planning to go with it. But still if there is any other solution to keep existing IP as it is while upgrading instance not associated with EIP ?

Comment: I don't think there is a way of stop/starting the instance to get a different instance type and also keeping an allocated IP.  Try talking to AWS support, see what they say

Comment: Support will likely tell you that you need an Elastic IP for this.  That's essentially the purpose of that feature.  Your app should not be dependent on a fixed IP, though.  It should be using DNS.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this a lesson as to why you should use a load balancer and a DNS entry, especially for anything public-facing. What were you going to do if you the instance failed?  Or the availability zone went down?

Personally I would spin up a set new larger instances behind a load balancer, create a Route53 DNS entry that points to the load balancer, and then release an update to the client that points to the DNS entry.  As clients update, traffic will gradually move to the load balancer. The undersized single instance's load will drop, so if it is overloaded it will eventually return to normal. Eventually you can kill the old instance when all/most clients have upgraded.

Comment: thank you so much for pointing out above stuffs, I will check them surely.